# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup

Tags: java, spring

I am currently trying to upgrade one of my spring applications from java 8 -> 11 and I am getting this error on startup:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:254)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:267)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
```

These are all my spring dependancies in my pom file:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Along with the spring boot starter parent version:
2.4.6

I am not sure what other information is need to let me know

Comment: I doubt that that are all your dependencies. That class has been added in newer Spring versions and not the version used with Spring Boot 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to specify a lower version of dependency?

I think that issue is with 2.4.X

From what I know 2.3.X will not cause any issues.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```